# Can't read text file yet passing is_open and good checks?

Tags: c++, string, fstream, stringstream

I'm getting an Access Violation Writing Location error while trying to load a text file. While debugging, I noticed that my "is_open()" and "good()" checks both pass because I reach "while (std::getline(myfile, line)). How is that possible? What's even dumber is that this very function works perfectly in a project of its own but for some reason I get the access violation error here.

// Header

```
static bool LoadObj(std::string file, std::vector<GLfloat> &out_vertices, std::vector<GLfloat> &out_normals);
```

// CPP

```
bool Resources::LoadObj(std::string file, std::vector<GLfloat> &out_vertices, std::vector<GLfloat> &out_normals)
{
std::string line;
std::ifstream myfile(file);

if (myfile.is_open())
{
    if (myfile.good())
    {
        while (std::getline(myfile, line))
        {
            if (!strncmp(line.c_str(), "v", 1))
            {
                std::string dummy;
                std::stringstream ss(line);
                ss >> dummy;

                while (ss >> line)
                {
                    out_vertices.push_back(std::stof(line));
                    std::cout << line;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

return false;
}
```

Comment: Access violations aren't anything to do with files that are open or not. Most likely the bug lies somewhere else.

Comment: A "Writing Location" error on an input file?

Comment: You're writing to memory you shouldn't be. Grab a debugger, and see which line it is happening on, and see what pointer you are misusing and how.

Comment: *"What's even dumber is that this very function works perfectly in a project of its own"* - even more evidence that the code's fine but your overall program has undefined behaviour and just happens to manifest that as a crash here.  You might try running under ValGrind or other analysis tools, or even switching to debug mode or another optimisation level - that might help the crash happen closer to the code causing it.

Comment: I'm debugging in VS2013 and I see that my std::string file comes through fine. But ifstream is saying "Error reading characters of string." I've tried the using a const char* for file instead of string as well and no luck. I've also set std::ios::in to specify this is simply a read.

Comment: I don't see how I'm writing to memory I shouldn't be. At first I thought it might be because I didn't declare my variables as static for this static function, but I don't think that matters from what I've read. Although if I make std::ifstream a static, the "Error reading characters of string" goes away and becomes just a NULL. Not sure if that's progress or just another wrong guess and check.

Comment: I take out everything in the function besides the ifstream declaration and the open and I get "  std::basic_ios<char,std::char_traits<char> > <Unable to read memory> 
"  Pic related: http://screencast.com/t/N6058AZhkJ7

Comment: See the solution to my other thread here for the fix: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26761708/fstream-included-but-ifstream-not-found-and-identifier-is-undefined/26891084#26891084][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26761708/fstream-included-but-ifstream-not-found-and-identifier-is-undefined/26891084#26891084

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the following question for the answer. Needed to include a lib and configure compiler settings. [fstream included but "ifstream not found" and "identifier is undefined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26761708/fstream-included-but-ifstream-not-found-and-identifier-is-undefined/26891084#26891084)