# fstream included but "ifstream not found" and "identifier is undefined"

Tags: c++, string, c++11, fstream

I don't know what to make of this. I've written a function that reads a .obj file, not unlike the dozens of other example functions out there for processing information from a text file. I've included fstream, iostream, and sstream. It compiles. Yet when I run it I get:

- An Unhandled Exception at a memory address (ntdll.dll) that complains
  about access violation writing location (I'm reading, not
  writing...).
- My variable watch on "ifstream myfile" reads identifier "myfile" is undefined". If I place a break on the "ifstream myfile(...)" line it reads "Unable to read memory" instead. Error reading characters of string also occurs just prior to the Unhandled Exception.
- Execution stops here in fstream during the getline call:

  ```
  virtual void __CLR_OR_THIS_CALL _Lock()
  {   // lock file instead of stream buffer
  if (_Myfile)
      _CSTD _lock_file(_Myfile);
  }
  ```

Relevant code, not much to see... pretty straight forward stuff. "file" is a const char* that reads "C:\cube.obj". Using namespace std.

```
ifstream myfile(file, ios::in);

if (myfile.is_open())
{
    if (myfile.good())
    {
        string line;
        while (std::getline(myfile, line))
        {
            // Foo
        }
    }
}

myfile.close();
```

I don't understand how on earth myfile is undefined despite straight up declaring it. fstream is clearly the right include and is accessible. The file is where it should be.

How can I debug this further? Teach me, oh wise ones. Using C++11 with Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: C:\ directory may be inaccessible to your program's privilege level.  Try putting cube.obj in, say, Documents.

Comment: From what I remember, you need to step past the declaration line before it will have the information on the created object.

Comment: Btw you don't need to close the ifstream, the destructor will do it.

Comment: @Deduplicator: .obj files (assuming the 3d object description file) are text files.

Comment: @Namfuak, I tried it from various folders, including the project folder. Still doesn't work.

Comment: @Stradigos: try enabling exceptions on your ifstream object, that might help pinpoint the problem. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/exceptions and an example here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/95a11d0599a925ca (note that Visual Studio error messages are more helpful)

Comment: @chris, I have stepped past it. That's how I've come to know the other things I posted above.

Comment: @Stradigos is this giving access violation or the code above runs fine but `myfile.is_open()` is false?

Comment: I suspect that you're clobbering the stream object somewhere in the part you call `// Foo`.

Comment: @Mr.kbok Good tip. Made the changes, doesn't give me anything new though. Same unhandled exception, same watch messages, etc.

Comment: BTW: All you need for reading is `ifstream myfile(file); string line; while (std::getline(myfile, line)) ...` - don't clutter the code with testing, manual closing, or redundant parameters.

Comment: @molbdnilo, Even if I comment out everything in foo I still have the same issue. In fact, it fails on the getline() call as stated above anyway. Never makes it. EDIT: Saw your BTW. Right, I've simplified the code as you've said. Still issues.

Comment: @MarcoA., is_open is true.

Comment: @Stradigos In that case, the error has happened before you even got to this code. But the `getline` will fail if an out-of-bounds array access (or use of a dangling pointer) somewhere (anywhere) overwrites the stream object. The "Unable to read memory" is usually an indication that an object has become corrupt.

Comment: Pic related: http://screencast.com/t/Dl9otgl0Q8m

Comment: @molbdnilo How would I track down such a pointer with visual studio? This is a large project... could take weeks, lol.

Comment: @Stradigos: By [making a testcase](http://sscce.org) (debugging 101). Yes, it _could_ take weeks. Welcome to life!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED! I knew it wasn't pointer related. Found this post, tried what it said, and it works flawlessly now. MSVCRTD.lib was missing in my dependencies. Why that's not mentioned anywhere as a prereq for using fstream is crazy. Can't believe the includes aren't enough.

"I had to change the Runtime Library setting to use Multi-threaded DLL (/MD) and then add: msvcrtd.lib to my dependencies, that solved my problems I was encountering for building in debug mode."

http://www.gamedev.net/topic/660218-strange-ifstream-crash/